# I want to delete a selected row(book including book_title, author, price, rent and category) using delete option as in attached image

Tags: javascript

[image]

I want to delete a selected row (book including book_title, author, price, rent and category) using delete option as in attached image.

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you delete the screenshot of your code in your question and post the code and format it as code? So it's easier for us to help you. maybe you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please paste some example code and edit your question to include a better description of the problem you're having and the things you're tried to this point.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with PHP easiliy.

What you have to do is a unique URL for each delete link:

```
<a href="viewbookdetails.php?delID=<?= $actualRowID ?>">Delete</a>
```

$actualRowID must be the unique ID of your row in your database table

This will open a page like:

```
...viewbookdetails.php?delID=27
```

27 in this example represents the ID of your affected row in your Table

Usualy you will generate a table like this:

```
<?php 
  foreach($array as $key)
  {
     $key['ID'].... //ID is your column name where your unique ID is in.
     echo "<td> my row.... </td>"; 
     echo "<td><a href="viewbookdetails.php?delID=".$key['ID'].">Delete</a> </td>"; 
  }
?>
```

This link will open your already opened "viewbookdetails.php" but it will attach an delID to it.

On you first line of viewbookdetail.php you could check for this parameter.

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_GET['delID']))
  {
     ...do your query like "DELETE FROM table WHERE ID = $_GET['delID']";
  }
?>
```

After this piece of code, your entry will be deleted.

Because your main processing and table generation will be below this code, the affected line will not be shown anymore.